# For loop to write several files in cloud storage from cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a cloud function in python to call a rest api get. The function response return a json file for each json file name passed to the function. The function works perfectly to a single call:

```
def request_func(x):
    url = 'https://use4.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/saas/api/v2/'+ x
    payload_headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json','icSessionId':ricSessionId}
    r = requests.get(url,headers=payload_headers)
    data = r.json()
    return data

def upload_blob(bucket_name, blob_text, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(blob_text)

wf_name = 'JOB_NAME'

data = request_func('workflow/name/'+ wf_name)
rid = data['id']
data = request_func('activity/activityLog?taskId='+rid)

def monitoramento(request):
    BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'
    BLOB_NAME = wf_name
    BLOB_STR = json.dumps(data)
    upload_blob(BUCKET_NAME, BLOB_STR, BLOB_NAME)
    return f'{wf_name} forecast json file success uploaded!'
```

I need to get several json files passed to the function then I made little adjustments to the function to use a FOR LOOP:

```
def request_func(x):
    url = 'https://use4.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/saas/api/v2/'+ x
    payload_headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json','icSessionId':ricSessionId}
    r = requests.get(url,headers=payload_headers)
    data = r.json()
    return data

def upload_blob(bucket_name, blob_text, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(blob_text)

list_jobs = ['JOB_NAME1','JOB_NAME2','JOB_NAME3']

for wf_name in list_jobs:

    data = request_func('workflow/name/'+ wf_name)
    rid = data['id']
    data = request_func('activity/activityLog?taskId='+rid)

    def monitoramento(request):
        BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'
        BLOB_NAME = wf_name
        BLOB_STR = json.dumps(data)
        upload_blob(BUCKET_NAME, BLOB_STR, BLOB_NAME)
```

The problem is that only the last object of the list, JOB_NAME3 json file, is writed to the bucket!
What I'm doing wrong?
I have omitted some code.

Comment: Where is `monitoramento()` called from? Tip: do not omit code. Create a minimum and reproducible example when asking for help.

Comment: Please do not use all caps to post your message.  Could you edit it to make it seem less like shouting?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm not a python developer so I achieved the code by researching. The monitoramento() function is not elsewhere in the entire code. What kind of minimum and reproducible example would you like, the json file response?

Comment: I recommend that you take the Stackoverflow tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. To create good programming questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you please be more specific and tell me in detail what point my question is not in complaince with good programming questions? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why are you defining a function inside of a loop?! As far as I can tell, that function never even runs.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile that's exactly what I need, some tips of I'm doing wrong! The fuction is running but only for the last value of the python list. Now at least I know where I need to focus on to solve my problem. Best regards

Comment: @RobertAlmeida It shouldn’t be running, are you sure it is? Could some other function create similar output?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile there is not other function to create similar output. However with your tip I could solve the problem. I got rid of the function inside of loop. For more people like you with really concern to help and not only to criticise. Best regards

Comment: @RobertAlmeida Should I summarize my comments as an answer?

Comment: Yes @AlexanderCécile that's for sure feel free

Answer (score 0):

With @AlexanderCécile tip I could solve my problem:

```
def request_func(x):
    url = 'https://use4.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/saas/api/v2/'+ x
    payload_headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json','icSessionId':ricSessionId}
    r = requests.get(url,headers=payload_headers)
    data = r.json()
    return data

def upload_blob(bucket_name, blob_text, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(blob_text)

list_jobs = ['JOB_NAME1','JOB_NAME2','JOB_NAME3']

for wf_name in list_jobs:
    data = request_func('workflow/name/'+ wf_name)
    rid = data['id']
    data = request_func('activity/activityLog?taskId='+rid)
    BUCKET_NAME = 'monitoramento'
    BLOB_NAME = wf_name
    BLOB_STR = json.dumps(data)
    upload_blob(BUCKET_NAME, BLOB_STR, BLOB_NAME)
```